# How to fix a phrase that is being repeated over multiple modals?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I am using two modals, and the title of the first modal is being repeated in the second one. I am using the modals to show a progress bar. I checked the PHP parts and there seems to be no error there, therefore I focused on the HTML part but was unable to solve the problem. Thank you for your help.

```
<button style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Award 2</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-content">
 <!-- Progress Bar-->
   <div class="above">

   <div class="show" style="margin-left:5%;border:none;">
   <!--The following text is being repeated -->
  <p ><?php echo $award2; ?></p> 
  </div>

   <div style="width:80%;display:block;margin-top:15px;margin-right:5%;margin-left:5%;height: 40px;margin-bottom: 30px" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $perc; ?>%;height:40px"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

 <button style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Award</button>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
 <!-- Progress Bar-->
    <div class="above">

     <div class="show" style="margin-left:5%;border:none;">
      <!--The following text should be the title -->
      <p style="color:#282828;font-size:30px"><?php echo $next_award; ?></p> 
   </div>
       <div style="width:80%;display:block;margin-top:15px;margin-right:5%;margin-left:5%;height: 40px;margin-bottom: 30px" class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $percent; ?>%;height:40px"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you have two modals both with the class bd-example-modal-lg. The data-target for both is that class. It would be better to give the modals a unique ID and use that as the data-target

Comment: @simon  That worked. Thank you